# Unable to get http POST data in Django view

Tags: ajax, angularjs, django

I'm using Angular to post some data to a Django endpoint with:

```
$http({
  method: 'POST',
  url: '/api/projects/166/interval_sort/',
  data: JSON.stringify({ids: [251,250,249,235,233,234]})
})
```

And in my view method, request.POST is an empty `<QueryDict: {}>`

```
def ProjectIntervalSort(request, pk):
  logger.debug("SORTABLE DATA: "+str(request.POST))
  return HttpResponse(status=204)
```

Chrome's network inspector shows my JSON object being sent, but I don't seem to be able to access it from the Django side. Am I not formatting the data correctly or missing something in my view method? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`request.POST` is for form-encoded data. You're using JSON, and you can find it in `request.body`.

Comment: Ah, perfect. SO will let me accept this in like 10 minutes. Thanks.